# Multitenant System with Sequences (on Azure)

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, database, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to utilize of the most elegant solution or use the lightest library to try and generate sequences for particular records.  This will be a multitenant system hosted in Azure using SQL Azure.  All the tenants will share the same database.  It is an ASP MVC4 application.

Tenant A and Tenant B both add in two different Expenses.
Each record will get a unique id (perhaps an INT or a GUID) that the system will use, however, each record needs a Tenant-Human-Readable ID that is an int also that increments for each tenant.  Why?  It would be nice for each tenant to have their own incrementing number that they can relate to.  Think of an Invoice Number, perhaps.

Eg,
Tenant A adds an expense.  PKEY = 1 / Sequence = 1
Tenant B adds an expense.  PKEY = 2 / Sequence = 1
Tenant A adds an expense.  PKEY = 3 / Sequence = 2

One solution would be to keep a table that would have the Sequence Type, Tenant ID, and Next Value and just query it & increment it right before I insert an Expense (to use the same example).  This seems like setting myself up for some poor database performance in the long term.

Is there another technique or perhaps a library that can help out in this situation?

Answer (score 3):

I've taken a slightly different approach. 
You could wrap this into a stored procedure...

It uses sequences, but it dynamically creates them when a new tenant is created.

```html
declare @Value int = null
Declare @Company_code varchar(10) = '00' -- Some value to indicate the tenant
Declare @SeqSchema varchar(20) = 'dbo'
Declare @SeqName varchar(50) = 'TestSequence_' + @Company_code
Declare @SeqFullName varchar(200) = quotename(@SeqSchema) + '.' + quotename(@SeqName)
Declare @Sql nvarchar(500)

if not exists (select object_id from sys.objects where object_id = OBJECT_ID(@SeqFullName) and type = 'SO')
Begin
 set @Sql = '
  CREATE SEQUENCE ' + @SeqSchema + '.' + @SeqName + @Company_code + ' as int
   START WITH 1
   INCREMENT BY 1
   MINVALUE 1
   MAXVALUE 999999
   NO CYCLE'

  exec sp_executesql @Sql
End

set @Sql = N'Set @Value = NEXT VALUE FOR ' + @SeqFullName
exec sp_executesql @Sql, N'@Value int output', @Value output;
print @Value
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a multi-tennant application running on Azure/SQL Azure. I am basically doing what you say. For example I have a schema like

```
Business Table
BusinessId - autoinc
Name

Client Table
ClientId - autoinc
BusinessId
Name
```

The business id is then used in the WHERE clause of SQL for and CRUD operations to ensure only the correct data is returned. I have created a few helper methods to make this easier. If you index correctly I don't believe there should be too many performance issues, I have never experienced any. A lot of my app settings are cached in memory as well to ease database load.